# multiple columns in body

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a form which I want to make 5 forms below in 5 columns in the body. I know that it is possible. Can you please help me ?

```
----------------------------------------------------
|              |                   |               |
| Column 1     |   Column 2        | Column 3      |
|              |                   |               |
----------------------------------------------------



   <table cellspacing="10">

 <tr>
<td><font color="black">*</font>Ref. No: </td> 
<td><input type="text"  onkeypress="return numeric(event); "value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['code'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);?>" name="code" ></td>
    </tr>

 <tr> 
<td><font color="black">*</font>Serial No: </td>
<td><input type="text"  value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['serialnumber'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['serialnumber']);?>" name="serialnumber"><br></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td><font color="black">*</font>Item Model: </td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['model'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['model']);?>" name="model"></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
<td><font color="black">*</font>Description </td>
<td> <input type="text"  value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['description'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);?>" name="description"><br></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: You want the `input` elements to be aligned in one row, rather than below each other?

Comment: @chris , 5 forms.

Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 but save form above. im gonna do multiple insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to your problem, while using tables, is to put all the labels in the first row, and all the inputs in the second.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyXgyW

```
<table cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td><font color="black">*</font>Ref. No: </td>
<td><font color="black">*</font>Serial No: </td>
<td><font color="black">*</font>Item Model: </td>
<td><font color="black">*</font>Description </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text"  onkeypress="return numeric(event); "value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['code'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);?>" name="code" ></td>
<td><input type="text"  value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['serialnumber'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['serialnumber']);?>" name="serialnumber"><br></td>
<td><input type="text"  value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['model'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['model']);?>" name="model"></td>
<td> <input type="text"  value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['description'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);?>" name="description"><br></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Expanding on this, you could nest your form table inside another four or five column table, like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyXgyW

Comment: oh im sorry , you didnt get my problem. pls see i added image above.

Comment: @codeSeven  so you want to have something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyXgyW  This was achieved by nesting tables inside table cells

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding the table:*

Each row in a table is tagged by `<tr>`.
In this  (row) you may insert any data as `<td>` (table data)
Column headers are tagged by `<th>` (table head(er))

*Regarding the form:*

To reach your goal you have to choose from 2 ways:

1. You use javascript to create a formData element and just add the data of the inputs. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
2. You create the form and add a table into it holding different inputs in the cells. Don't forget to name them so you can reach the data to serverside.

I would choose the first way.